# When does proof by contradiction occur in Cantor's diagonalization proof?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Cantor's diagonalization argument says that given a list of the reals, one can choose a unique digit position from each of those reals, and can construct a new real that was not previously listed by ensuring it does not match any of those digit position's place values. The conclusion is that $| \Bbb{R}| > |\Bbb{Z}|$. Let's call the function that produces digits of the unlisted real $D$.

The proof by contradiction starts by assuming a list $X$ containing all reals, therefore $|X|=|\Bbb{R}|$. Let's say that $x_{i,j}$ is the $j$-th digit of the $i$-th element of $X$ and $j \in \Bbb{Z}$. Any digits not present are assumed to be zero-valued. (Correct me if I make any invalid assumptions along the way.) For the moment let's only say of $i$ that it can take on positive and negative values, which is easily justified by $X$ containing positive and negative reals.

Let's call $y$ the unlisted real produced by diagonalization, and $y_k$ are the digits of the unlisted real. $k \in \Bbb{Z}$. Though many ways to produce place values exist, lets settle for:

$$D(k) = y_k = (x_{k,k} + 1) \mod 10$$

This means the domain of $D$ is $\Bbb{Z}$.

However, by definition, the diagonalization process must consume all elements of $X$, and so D must be a function that can be invoked with a unique input the same number of times as there are elements in $X$. Again, we assumed that $|X|=|\Bbb{R}|$. This means that the cardinality of the domain of $D$ is $| \Bbb{R} |$. If we accept that $| \Bbb{R}| > |\Bbb{Z}|$, then we have:

- the domain of $D$ is $\Bbb{Z}$.
- the cardinality of the domain of $D$ is $| \Bbb{R} |$
- $| \Bbb{R}| > |\Bbb{Z}|$

A contradiction is formed before we even attempt to produce a $y$. My interpretation of this contradiction is that, If we accept that $| \Bbb{R}| > |\Bbb{Z}|$, then we must also accept that the function $D$ cannot exist, and therefore diagonalization is impossible.

To my question, **shouldn't the impossibility of diagonalization mean that it is not useful for proving $| \Bbb{R}| > |\Bbb{Z}|$?**

I keep thinking that $D$ is similar (what's the precise word?) to some $D'$ where the input is some element of $X$, and the output is an unique $i$ from $y_i$. That would be $D': \Bbb{R} \rightarrow \Bbb{Z}$, a demonstration of a bijection all on its own. Perhaps that a list can contain the reals, and that $D$ exists, are the same assumption, and by that, we can reach the contradiction articulated by Cantor.

Comment: The usual proof goes like this: you *assume* there is a surjective map from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, and then use diagonalization to produce a real number not in the image of that map, which contradicts the surjectivity. Therefore the assumption must be false: there is no surjective map from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. This implies there is no injective map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ (actually these two statements are equivalent under AC).

Comment: Isn't that the same as a list of the reals?

Comment: For what it's worth, proof by contradiction can be avoided. One simply proves that for each function $f:{\mathbb N} \rightarrow {\mathbb R},$ there exists (in fact, one can construct explicitly) a real number that does not belong to $\{f(x): x \in {\mathbb N}\}.$

Comment: Yes, I'm just trying to state it in a concise way; also for me it's more natural to use $\mathbb{N}$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}$, although they are basically the same. I don't fully understand you question, but it seems you are confused about the distinction between the map $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ (which is assumed to be surjective) and the diagonalization process. After fixing such a map $f$, you recursively construct a real number $x$: choose the tenth digit of $x$ to be different from tenth digit of $f(1)$, hundredth digit of $x$ different from that of $f(2)$, etc.

Comment: While the common expositions of the proof often begins by  assuming you have a surjection, *this is not necessary*. One can avoid contradictions completely, and simply show how to construct, for a given function $f\colon\mathbb{N}\to[0,1]$, a number $s_f\in [0,1]$ with the property that $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, $f(n)\neq s_f$. There are no "arguments by contradiction" embedded there. I usually object to the "proof by contradiction" casting because the assumption of surjectivity is unnecessary. I call these proofs "fake proofs-by-contradiction"; similar issues with infinity of primes.

Comment: @xXF: I really wish you wouldn't assert that one assumes the function is surjective. That is a completely unnecessary assumption that is never used in the argument until you have explicitly produced a number not in the range, and then you trot out the assumption from the wings to center stage to say "Ta-da! Contradiction!" A completely unnecessary complication, when removing that initial assumption and that final line gives you a perfectly fine proof of "for every $f\colon\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$, there is $r_f\in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathrm{Im}(f)$".

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I agree starting the proof by assuming surjectivity is making things worse. It seems all we need is the equivalence between $\forall x\lnot\phi(x)$ and $\lnot\exists x\phi(x)$. Does this equivalence involve any law of contradiction?

Comment: @xXF: I don't think you need any such equivalence. We are proving "there does not exist a surjection"; we do this by showing "for every function, there is an element of the codomain that is not in the image".

Comment: I give a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/39285/742) with no argument by contradiction showing that there is no surjection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $2^{\mathbb{N}}$; it is an easy matter to establish a bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ and $2^{\mathbb{N}}$, e.g. using Cantor-Bernstein, and so there can be no surjection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin "Any list is not complete" is not literally the same as "there does not exist complete list". I think the former translates to $\forall x\lnot\phi(x)$ where $\phi(x)$ says "the list $x$ is complete" while the latter translates to $\lnot\exists x\phi(x)$. Sometimes people take both $\forall$ and $\exists$ to be primitive symbols in first order logic, and sometimes people define $\forall x$ as $\lnot\exists x\lnot$. In any case I feel that at least we need something like $p\leftrightarrow\lnot\lnot p$, which I believe requires some extent of law of contradiction.

Comment: "A contradiction is formed before we even attempt to produce a $y.$" Setting aside the question of whether contradiction is necessary to prove this particular fact, it seems to me that in *every* proof by contradiction, a contradiction is formed before we even attempt to "produce a $y$" or whatever it is that the proof attempts to do. At some point we say "assume $P$" and at that instant the contradiction is already implicit. The rest of the work to "produce a $y$" is simply to demonstrate a contradiction that already exists.

Comment: @xXF: $p\iff \neg\neg p$ is excluded middle, not "law of contradiction". In any case, you don't need an equivalence, you need an implication. But at that level, it's really irrelevant. *This* argument, built atop standard logic, is a direct argument of a stated proposition, not a proof by contradiction.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I'm surprised that there's a bijection between $\Bbb{R}$ and $2^\Bbb{N}$. I'm thinking of scientific notation, where you have a mantissa that's a $\Bbb{Z}$ and an exponent that's a $\Bbb{Z}$, but that only gives us $\Bbb{Q}$. I'll have to come to grips with your linked answer though, since at first glance it seems you might be using a different meaning of $2^\Bbb{N}$ than the power set.

Comment: @Brent: "where you have a mantissa that's a $\mathbb{Z}$..." I have no idea what it is you are thinking. There is a very easy bijection between $(0,1)$ and $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$: $f(x) = -\pi/2+x\pi$. There is a very easy bijection between $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ and $\mathbb{R}$: just use $f(x)=\arctan(x)$. And there are easy injection going each way between $2^{\mathbb{N}}$ and $(0,1)$: from $(0,1)$, write in binary, picking one representation uniformly when required; and from $2^{\mathbb{N}}$, send the sequestion $\sigma$ to the real number with $5$ in position $n$ if $\sigma(n)=0$, and $6$ otherwise.

Comment: @Brent: (cont) Cantor-Bernstein then tells you (without arguments by contradictions) that from the injections $(0,1)\to 2^{\mathbb{N}}$ and $2^{\mathbb{N}}\to (0,1)$ you can construct a bijection $2^{\mathbb{N}}\to (0,1)$. Not just compose the bijections $2^{\mathbb{N}}\to(0,1)\to(-\pi/2,\pi/2)\to\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Would you point me to an example?

Comment: The answer I link to above provides such a proof.